# J3.8 Module Manager Articles Category generating wrong links

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla3.8

The list of categories in Module Manager Arcticles Cateogries is generating wrong links. It's like the News section doesn't have subcategories. The Title is displayed, but all have the same main category link.

I have routing set on Experimental. When i set routing on Stable the links are working. Problem i have is that, when routing is set on Stable, search results generate wrong links.

Why is the link generated wrong im Joomla 3.8? How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]